# Group of order 81 and exponent 3

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

I know that there is one group only of order 81 which is non abelian and of exponent 3. But I have no idea how to prove it.

This question is personal. I looked at Wims, which suggested the answer.
The group is the direct product $G=T\times C_3$, where $T$ is the upper unipotent  triangular matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb F_3$ and where $C_3$ is the cyclic group of order $3$.

In order to reach to $G$, I tried of course the standard methods, from the derived subgroup to the Frattini of such a $3$-group, which appeared all to be useless. I think now that I miss some technique which is relevant to the problem. 
I need the magic word behind this exercice. I will manage for the rest.

May I have any hint in this direction?

Thanks

Yvette

Comment: I made a small progress. If one  proves that the group $G$ has a maximal subgroup which is abelian, then we are done. Indeed, the  group $G$ is then the semi-direct product of $C_3^3$ with one of the many subgroups $C_3$ in $G$. But we have only two conjugacy classes of elements of orfer $3$ in ${\rm GL}(3,\mathbb F_3)$. One gives our group and the other gives a group which is not of exponent $3$.

Comment: With Alain Debreil's help, I think that I have now the solution. If all subgroups of order $27$ are non commutative, the center $Z$ is forcibly of order 3, and all maximal subgroups must be isomorphic to $T$.

Comment: But $T$ has only one normal  subgroup of order $3$, which is then characteristic in $T$, and invariant in $G$. But It is well know that a subgroup invariant of order $3$ is central. So all the $C_3\neq Z$ are non normal and their normalisateur is not of order 27 for the same reason as before.

Comment: The normalizer of a such $H=C_3$ is of order 9, since $H$ is normal in the subgroup generated by $Z$ and itself. It follows that  the cardinal of the conjugacy class of $H$ is $9$: not compatible with the fact that we have $39$ such $H$.